How to get the date difference between two jalali date (persianDatepicker) on clicking the second input date picker?
I use this https://github.com/behzadi/persianDatepicker script to show jalali date
I select date1 and date2 to from datepicker to my input
Code


$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.example').persianDatepicker({
    format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
    observer: true,
    altField: '.observer-example-alt',
    autoClose: true,
  });
});
html,
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0;
}

label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
}
<strong>Persian Date Difference</strong>
<label for="start-date">Start Date</label>
<input id="start-date" class="example" name="start-date" />
<label for="stop-date">Stop Date</label>
<input id="end-date" class="example" name="end-date" />
<label for="diff">Difference</label>
<input id="diff" class="diff" name="diff" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--  https://github.com/behzadi/persianDatepicker -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Behzadi/persianDatepicker/css/persianDatepicker-default.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Behzadi/persianDatepicker/js/persianDatepicker.js"></script>



I want when I select date1 (id="start-date") and   date 2 (id="end-date") it will immediately display in (id="diff") the difference between the two jalali dates
for example 1
date1= 1403/06/06 
date2= 1403/06/06  

result:
1 day

example 2
date1= 1403/06/06 
date2= 1403/06/07   

result:
2 days

i dont add what add in my javascript to earn my result
<script>
??????
??????
</script>


I change the plug in
this is my answrs
https://github.com/majidh1/JalaliDatePicker/issues/114

I change the plug in this is my answrs
github.com/majidh1/JalaliDatePicker/issues/114
